# ADO.Net vs Bound Controls

Tags: ado.net

Is there any compromise regarding resources, if I use bound controls on my asp.net app versus ado.net?

When is it best to use bound controls and when is it best to use ado.net to connect to database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bound controls use ADO.NET; they are not competing tools but complementary tools.  One uses each other, or you use an Object Relational Mapper, which under the scenes may use ADO.NET.

Does that make sense?  For more information on the two, the asp.net web site has a learn section with a lot of good resources.